# Execute function from SwiftUI view to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, model, scnnode

I have `GlobeView()` embedded in a SwiftUI view. I want to call a function to execute from the SwiftUI view to the `GlobeViewController`.

What's the easiest way I can achieve this given this layered view hierarchy?
I know I can pass down a simple closure, but in doing so, I get a bug where `SCNParticleSystem` is infinitely added to the `SceneView` since the init fires every time the view updates.

Is there an alternative approach where I can call this function?
Is there a way to detect variable changes in `viewModel` from `GlobeViewController`?
I know I can use `didset` on `viewModel`, but how would I know when a specific member variable of `viewModel` is set?

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import CoreImage
import MapKit

class GlobeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var option: Int = 2
    @Published var hideSearch: Bool = false
    @Published var executeFunction: Bool = false
}

struct MainProfile: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        GlobeView() //call function from here
    }
}

typealias GenericControllerRepresentable = UIViewControllerRepresentable

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private struct GlobeViewControllerRepresentable: GenericControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GlobeViewController {
        let globeController = GlobeViewController(earthRadius: 1.0, popRoot: viewModel)
        return globeController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GlobeViewController, context: Context) { }
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public struct GlobeView: View {
    
    public var body: some View {
        GlobeViewControllerRepresentable()
    }
}

public typealias GenericController = UIViewController
public typealias GenericColor = UIColor
public typealias GenericImage = UIImage

public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    public var earthNode: SCNNode!
    internal var sceneView : SCNView!
    private var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    
    init(popRoot: GlobeViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = popRoot
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    init(popRoot: GlobeViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = popRoot
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: You start by moving `viewModel` from `GlobeViewController` to `MainProfile`. Meaning you'd remove its declaration in both `GlobeViewController` and `GenericControllerRepresentable` and initialize it in `MainProfile`. Please add your `GlobeViewModel`'s code to better help you.

Comment: @PierreJanineh I added the GlobeViewModel code. I understand you want me to only init GlobeViewModel in MainProfile. But GlobeViewModel is an environment object initialized at the base of my app. In my case I want GlobeViewController to have a reference of GlobeViewModel so that I can directly modify variables from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part 1***

The key to getting the the particle system (or anything else) to only initialize once is understanding how and when SwiftUI recreates the View.

Right now your `GlobeViewControllerRepresentable` calls `updateUIViewController` anytime anything in the `@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobeViewModel` changes.

Because of this the `updateUIViewController` can easily become complex because you have to create a series of checks to make sure you aren't duplicating work.

But the alternative is to use SwiftUI's storage and identity management in your favor...

First, your ViewModel (or whatever anyone else prefers to call it) should be initialized as a `@StateObject`. **This is very important.**

```
@StateObject var viewModel: GlobeViewModel = .init()
```

Second, the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` should be as simple as possible (No SwiftUI property wrappers or additional arguments).

```
private struct GlobeViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = GlobeViewController
    
    let viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GlobeViewController {
        print(#function)
        return UIViewControllerType(popRoot: viewModel)
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GlobeViewController, context: Context) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

These 2 things ensure that `makeUIViewController` and `updateUIViewController` only get called once because `GlobeViewControllerRepresentable` identity is tied to the `StateObject`.

Once this is setup you can have a UIKit setup and a SwiftUI setup (best of both worlds).

***Part 2***

To call a function from the `UIViewController` in `SwiftUI` you can create a reference to the `UIViewController` in the `ViewModel`.

```
class GlobeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    weak var controller: GlobeViewController?
    @Published var option: Int = 2
    @Published var hideSearch: Bool = false
    @Published var executeFunction: Bool = false
    @Published var earthRadius: Int = 1
    
    func increaseRadius() {
        guard let controller else {return}
        controller.increaseRadius()
    }
}
```

And to observe the changes in the ViewModel you can use `Combine`

```
import Combine
public class GlobeViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var viewModel: GlobeViewModel!
    
    private var anyCancellable: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()
    
    init(popRoot: GlobeViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = popRoot
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        viewModel.controller = self
        
        viewModel.$earthRadius.sink { [weak self] radius in
            print("new earth radius \(radius)")
        }.store(in: &anyCancellable)
    }
    deinit {
        anyCancellable.removeAll()
        viewModel.controller = nil
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button: UIButton = .init(frame: .zero)
        button.setTitle("Increase Radius", for: .normal)
        button.configuration = .borderedProminent()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseRadius), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        //pin to edges
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    }
    @objc func increaseRadius() {
        viewModel.earthRadius += 1
    }
    
}
```

You can test this code with the code above and

```
struct MainProfile: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: GlobeViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(viewModel.earthRadius, format: .number)
            GlobeViewControllerRepresentable(viewModel: viewModel) //call function from here
            Button("Increase Radius") {
                viewModel.increaseRadius()
            }
        }.environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainProfile()
}
```

You'll notice in the sample that `increaseRadius` declared in the `UIViewController` is called by the `Button` via the ViewModel and the `sink` `print` when the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `GlobeViewModel` is an environment object initialized at the base of your app, and you want `GlobeViewController` to have a direct reference to it, your current approach should work: You are already passing the `GlobeViewModel` to `GlobeViewController` via the initializer.

The challenge is to execute a function in `GlobeViewController` from `GlobeView` without causing issues like multiple initializations of `SCNParticleSystem`.

You could try and implement a mechanism in `GlobeViewController` to observe changes in `GlobeViewModel`, and react accordingly.

```
+--------------------+         +--------------------------+
|                    |         |                          |
|   MainProfile      |         |    GlobeView             |
|   (SwiftUI View)   |         |    (SwiftUI View)        |
|   @ObservedObject  |         |   Uses EnvironmentObject |
|    viewModel       |         |    viewModel             |
|                    |         |                          |
+---------+----------+         +--------------+-----------+
          |                                   |
          | Pass viewModel                    | Pass viewModel
          |                                   |
          v                                   v
+---------+----------+         +-------------+------------+
|                    |         |                          |
|  GlobeViewModel    |---------|  GlobeViewController     |
| (ObservableObject) |         |  (UIKit ViewController)  |
|                    |         |                          |
+--------------------+         +--------------------------+
```

The `GlobeViewController` would be:

```swift
public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    private var isParticleSystemInitialized = false

    // Existing initializer code

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup observer for executeFunction
        viewModel.$executeFunction.sink { [weak self] newValue in
            if newValue {
                self?.executeRequiredFunction()
            }
        }.store(in: &cancellables) // Assuming you have a collection of AnyCancellable
    }

    private func executeRequiredFunction() {
        // Check to avoid reinitialization
        if !isParticleSystemInitialized {
            // Your logic to initialize SCNParticleSystem
            isParticleSystemInitialized = true
        }
    }
}
```

`GlobeViewController` observes changes in `GlobeViewModel` using Combine's `sink` method. That setup allows `GlobeViewController` to react to changes in the view model.

The `isParticleSystemInitialized` flag makes sure the initialization of `SCNParticleSystem` occurs only once, preventing the issue of multiple initializations.

Since `GlobeViewModel` is an environment object, you can pass it to `GlobeViewController` without reinitializing it in `MainProfile`.

See if that would maintain the connection between `GlobeViewController` and `GlobeViewModel`, allowing direct modification of variables, while also preventing the reinitialization issue you were experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the View model object, in SwiftUI that's what `let`, `body`, `@State` and `@Binding` are for. In your `UIViewControllerRepresentable` it is essential to implement the `updateUIViewController` func which is called whenever a `let`, `@State` or `@Binding` value is changed. That is where you use the struct's values to update your view controller object (if any values have changed since last time).  `UIViewControllerRepresentable` works the same as `View`, i.e. in a `View`, `body` is called whenever a `let`, `@State` or `@Biniding` is changed, and in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, `updateUIViewController` is called whenever a `let`, `@State` or `@Biniding` is changed in exactly the same way. Use `let` for read access, use `@Binding var` for read/write. Place the State at highest common parent of all the `View` structs or `UIViewControllerRepresentable` structs where the data is needed. Something like this:

```
private struct GlobeViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let isInitialized: Bool // let because view controller doesn't write to this
    
    // called once
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GlobeViewController {
        GlobeViewController(earthRadius: 1.0)
    }
    
    // called every time a `let` or `@Binding var` changes.
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GlobeViewController, context: Context) { 
        if isInitialized && !uiViewController.isParticleSystemInitialized {
            uiViewController.executeRequiredFunction()
        }
    }
}
```