# How to access ARView instance in UIViewRepresentable instance

Tags: swiftui, uikit, arkit

The standard pattern for using an `ARView` (UIkit / RealityKit / ARkit type) in SwiftUI is to define a `UIViewRepresentable` struct and use this in the app's `ContentView`
as follows:

```
struct ContentView : View {
   var body: some View {
      ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        // configure arView
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```

In later code I would like to be able to access the `arView` object generated by the
`makeUIView` method. The following attempt to make `arView` a property doesn't
work since `ARViewContainer` is a struct
and thus can not have a mutable property:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var arView : ARView!  // ERROR : struct is immutable
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        // configure arView
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```

I can do the following, but this feels wrong and I suspect that the instance
is meant to be reusable (e.g. a Singleton) and this breaks that pattern
(I only have a single `ARView` instance in my app, but the code still smells bad):

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = (frame: .zero)
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // configure arView
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```

So how can a "capture" the `arView` object created by `makeUIView` so
I can accesss it later? What I ultimately want to do is to be able to capture
AR frames when the user taps the screen or a button, but to do this I somehow
need to get access to the `arView` instance:

```
let currentFrame = arView.session.currentFrame
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569851/execute-function-from-swiftui-view-to-view-controller/77571500#77571500

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with a let Bool to signal you want to capture something and a binding var to put the data into, e.g.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    let capturing: Bool
    @Binding var frames: [Frame]

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        if capturing && context.coordinator.isCapturing == false {
           context.coordinator.startCapturing()
        }

        if !capturing && context.coordinator.isCapturing == true {
           context.coordinator.stopCapturing()
        }

        
        context.coordinator.didCapture = { frame
            frames += frame
        }

       
    }

    class Coordinator: ARSessionDelegate {
        …
    }
```

Comment: Is `updateUIView` called on every frame?

Comment: `updateUIView` was only called once in my last test. I instead use an `ARSessionDelegate` that does receive every frame.

Comment: It’s called whenever the lets or vars change. It wasn’t clear you wanted to capture more than one frame, I’ll update the code